# Not understaning how jenkins ci build works

Tags: mysql, bash, continuous-integration, jenkins

i have my project in jenkins, when you build it, it finds the script/cibuild script and executes whatever you have in there. I run the script from my project directory and all is fine, i run the build from jenkins, i get errors? i dont understand?

my script/cibuild script:

```
#!/bin/sh   
# This script file is the entry point to ci.miranetworks.net build/test process.
# It is executed by jenkins, from the root directory
#

echo "1. cd into script "
cd script
echo "2. run createmysqldb test_traffic test_user password"
./createmysqldb test_traffic test_user password
echo "3. cd back into root dir "
cd ..
echo "4. create table with sql with: "
mysql -u test_user --password=password test_traffic < ./phoenix/data/sql/lib.model.schema.sql

export WORKSPACE=phoenix
export SYMFONY=$WORKSPACE/lib/vendor/symfony/lib
(cd $WORKSPACE
  echo "6. Clearing the cache"
  ./symfony cc
  echo "7. Run unit test"
  ./symfony php test/unit/RbcTest.php
)

echo "8. All done and exiting"
exit 0
```

so when i log onto mysql command with mysql -u test_user --password=password test_traffic it is succesfull then i do GRANT ALL and i also get:

```
 ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'test_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

although in createmysqldb i do: Q2="GRANT ALL ON **.** TO '$2'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$3';"

can anyone explain why i get an access denied?
I have another issue with the same script but want to sort out this one first :)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as in MySQL i know you need to change

```
ALL ON . TO ...
```

into

```
ALL ON .* TO ...
```

to grant access to all tables ?

Comment: oops sorry dont know why wild cards did not show, but i DO have it as GRANT ALL ON asterisk.asterisk TO '$2'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$3';"  my asteriksk dont wanna show...